# Leaflet Turf.buffer projection

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, turf

I successfully created a buffer on Leaflet with Turf.JS .
I had to change the map CRS to WGS84 (epsg:4326) to make it work. But the problem is that I need to go back to the default CRS of Leaflet which is EPSG:3857 , and that code make the buffer look like an egg, in Europe.

How could I change that code?

```
 var x, myFunction, data, features, buffered, bufferedLayer;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var xdiv = x/100;
  var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
  var buffered = turf.buffer(data, xdiv,{units: 'kilometers'});
        var bufferedLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
        bufferedLayer.addData(buffered);
            drawnItems.addLayer(bufferedLayer); 
        bufferedLayer.addTo(map);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turf is using geodesic buffer. You will never be able to get a round buffer on an EPSG 3857 map. You can always make a cartesian buffer but it will be quite wrong...

An example with EPSG 3857 using [reproject](https://github.com/perliedman/reproject) library, [jsts](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts), [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) and Leaflet below. You can also look at [the demo](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/f1a627d4af91444f3fcaea66c62c8319). It's mainly useful in my opinion when using a local projection that preserve locally quite well distance, area and angle unlike here.

`bundle.js` mentioned in the sample is a file generated from reproject library using `npm run bundle` (you can also found it in the mentioned live demo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jsts@2.3.0/dist/jsts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.5/proj4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
  crossorigin=""/>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #map {
        /* configure the size of the map */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // initialize Leaflet
      var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 2.18, lat: 46}, 8);
      var epsg3857 = proj4.Proj("EPSG:3857");
      var crss = {
        "EPSG:3857": epsg3857
      };
      var pt = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [2.18, 46]
        }
      };
      
      // Reproject geometry coordinates to EPSG 3857
      var point3857geometry = reproject.reproject(pt.geometry, proj4.WGS84, epsg3857, crss);

      // Convert GeoJSON geometry with EPSG 3857 coordinates to jsts geometry
      var geojsonReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
      var ptJsts = geojsonReader.read(point3857geometry);
      // Create a 40000 meters buffer in "local" projection 3857
      var bufferPtJsts = ptJsts.buffer(40000);
      // Write back the generate buffer to GeoJSON
      var geojsonWriter = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();
      var bufferGeoJSON = geojsonWriter.write(bufferPtJsts, 32);
      // Reproject geomtry of buffer to WGS84
      var bufferWGS84 = reproject.reproject(bufferGeoJSON, epsg3857, proj4.WGS84, crss);
      console.log(bufferWGS84);
      // Copy input feature and change geometry to polygon buffer
      var bufferFeature = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pt));
      bufferFeature.geometry = bufferWGS84;
      // Add GeoJSON as a Leaflet layer
      var myLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
      myLayer.addData(bufferFeature);

      // add the OpenStreetMap tiles
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      }).addTo(map);

      // show the scale bar on the lower left corner
      L.control.scale().addTo(map);

      // show a marker on the map
      L.marker({lon: 0, lat: 0}).bindPopup('The center of the world').addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello. I tried to better understand your code. How can I use the "drawnItems" from Leaflet.draw instead of a given point? I've got a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')" error.

Comment: Try `drawnItems.toGeoJSON().features.filter(el => el.geometry.type == 'Point').map(el => el.geometry)`. It returns an array of element similar to `pt.geometry`. You need to reuse most of my code in a loop with my additional info.